# Complement of the Brill Noether locus in $\mathcal{M}_g$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_g$ of genus $g$ curves over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $d,r\geq 1$ be integers so that the Brill Noether number 
$\rho(g,r, d)=g-(r+1)(g-d+r)>0$ . I am mainly interested in the case when $r=1$.

Consider the locus $\mathcal{W}^r_d=\{C\in \mathcal{M}_g: W^r_d(C)\neq\emptyset\}$.

Here $W^r_d(C)=\{L\in Pic^d(C): h^0(L)\geq r+1\}$.

It is known that $\mathcal{W}^r_d$ is an open dense set in $\mathcal{M}_g$. What is the codimension of it's complement in the moduli space?

Thank you.

Comment: If $\rho$ is nonnegative, then the set that you call $\mathcal{W}^r_d$ equals all of $\mathcal{M}_g$.  When $\rho$ equals $-1$, $\mathcal{W}^r_d$ is a divisor.  This is part of the proof that $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ is of general type for $g$ large (Harris, Mumford, Eisenbud).

Comment: @Jason Starr. Thank you. The purpose of my question is as follows. In ACGH, it says that as a corollary of the Fulton Lazarsfeld connectedness theorem, for a general curve $C$, if $\rho\geq 1$, then $W^r_d(C)$ is irreducible. I thought 'general' here meant Brill Noether general. But all curves in the moduli space are Brill Noether general?

Comment: No, not all curves are Brill-Noether general.  However, you defined $W^r_d(C)$ using an inequality, i.e., $h^0(L) \geq r+1$ rather than $h^0(L)=r+1$.  With that definition, whenever $\rho\geq 0$, the set $W^r_d(C)$ is nonempty for all smooth, genus $g$ curves $C$.  Saying that $C$ is "Brill-Noether general" *usually* means that for all $\rho$ with $\rho<0$, $W^r_d(C)$ is empty (some authors would add the condition that the spaces $G^r_d(C)$ are all smooth).

Comment: @Jason Starr. Ah sorry, I don't think I follow your comment. In the corollary to the connectedness theorem, it says for a general curve $C$, if $\rho\geq 1$, then the variety is irreducible. What does general mean in this context? Because $\rho< 1$ is not valid here.

Comment: The question you asked above is different from the question you asked in your most recent comment.  Nonemptiness of $W^r_d(C)$ is different from irreducibility of $W^r_d(C)$.  Does that help clear up your confusion?

Comment: With regard to user52991's first response to Jason, my recollection is that in ACGH, at the point the comment is made, one also knows that on a general curve, all the $W^r_d$ are smooth.  From Fulton-Lazarsfeld we have that the $W^r_d$  are connected.  That $W^r_d$  is irreducible follows.

Comment: @aginensky, I would like to know what is meant by general in that context (when $W^r_d$ are irreducible). It means such curves for an open subset of the moduli space. Is there a description of this open set or codimension of its complement?

Comment: @user...  I don't know of a good description.  Surely Jason is far more expert in such things as I.  Perhaps one can make a statement about injectivity of the Petri maps as the criteria. My statement, as well as the statement in ACGH (I believe) are about one general curve.